# How to find the Coefficients of each Cosine term that makes up a discrete signal?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have a discrete sequence of N real values. Is there a way to find a list of N-1 real numbers x[n] so that this:

[image]

with the nth coefficient is x[n], and each element in my original list is y[k], with k representing the index of the element in the list, starting from k=0, is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a discrete cosine transform of Type III, as shown [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html) or its [inverse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.idct.html).

Comment: I used scipy.fft.dct (type=3) then applied scipy.fft.dct on it. While the shape of the signal is the same as the original, the values are much larger (I mean 1.8 vs 125000). Is that normal?

Comment: I don't know. In FFT you can get much larger values due to the implicit `1/N` factors, here I don't know.

Comment: It depends on the definition/implementation of the FFT. But this is not a bug, this is how it's defined. You can always check if you get what you wanted by applying your formula above to the series.

Comment: Oh, I fixed the problem for the dct-- I just used norm='ortho' for both of them.